# How do I set an option for a subproject of a subproject in meson?

Tags: gstreamer, meson-build

Inside my `meson.build`, I have the following dependency:

```
gst_dep  = dependency(
    'gstreamer-1.0'
  , version: '>= 1.22'
  , default_options: [
        'tests=disabled'
      , 'examples=disabled'
      , 'gst-examples=disabled'
      , 'introspection=enabled'
      ]
  )
```

I also have a `.wrap` file for GStreamer inside the `subprojects` folder. The above works well. However, I need to instruct a subproject of GStreamer that I don't need OpenH264. I tried this:

```
gst_dep  = dependency(
    'gstreamer-1.0'
  , version: '>= 1.22'
  , default_options: [
        'tests=disabled'
      , 'gst-plugins-bad:openh264=disabled'
      , 'examples=disabled'
      , 'gst-examples=disabled'
      , 'introspection=enabled'
      ]
  )
```

Meson complains:

```
ERROR: In subproject gstreamer: Unknown options: "gstreamer:openh264"
```

Is there a cure?